# ImportError: cannot import name. Can't figure out why

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, blender, importerror

I have three python files, in a folder.

My folder structure looks like so:

```
RenderAddon (folder)
---- __init__.py
---- config.py
---- QuickRenderAddon.py
```

I try to run `__init__.py`, but I get this error:

**Error:**

```
"RenderAddon\__init__.py", line 22
    from . import config
    ImportError: cannot import name 'config'
```

**Complete traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Blender_271\2.71\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 299, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\EinarAune\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\scripts\addons\RenderAddon\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import config
ImportError: cannot import name 'config'
```

I can't figure out why. What's wrong?

---

**__init__.py**

```
if "bpy" in locals():
    import imp
    imp.reload(config)
    imp.reload(QuickRenderAddon)
    print("Reloaded multifiles")
else:
    from . import config
    from . import QuickRenderAddon
    print("Imported multifiles")

import bpy
import os
```

**QuickRenderAddon.py**

```
import bpy
import os
from . import config
```

No imports in **config.py**

Comment: Which directory are you running it from and what command are you using to run?

Comment: I'm running this script through the 3D software Blender. It's an addon, and I get this message when trying to activate the addon via Blender. I've updated my answer with the complete traceback.

Also, I'm therefore not using any commands myself. And I don't know what commands Blender is using to run the script.

Comment: From what you describe it is not seeing that "C:\Users\EinarAune\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\scripts\addons\RenderAddon\config.py" exists. I used the same structure as yours and don't see the error. The only time I see the exact error is when the file is missing. You  may want to put some debug code to and check if python sees that the file exists

Comment: Try adding some debug prints maybe? print (os.getcwd()) and print (sys.path) might be good to add to the top of that __init__ file.  If you do "import config", the path to config.py should either be the working folder or somewhere in sys.path.

Comment: I added the debugging print-commands and found that the path user3885927 posted didn't exist. Windows had a different language setting for those paths. Changed the OS language and now it works like a charm. Thanks, both of you.

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to your title. Rather, accept the answer that solved the problem. If no answer solved your problem, then write one and accept your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the debugging print-commands and found that the path user3885927 posted didn't exist. Windows had a different language setting for those paths. Changed the OS language and now it works like a charm. Thanks, both of you

Answer (score 2):

`from . import config` will try to import a "config" name from `__init__.py`, you should instead do `import config`

Comment: I tried changing it, but I just got a different error: No module name 'config'